Add Geometry Data to Layer with no Geometry in QGIS
I'm working with two layers in QGIS: one with tabular meteorological data and one with geometry data. The tabular data contains meteorological station IDs along with wind speed and date (stn, wind_speed, date), while the geometry layer includes station names and their geometries (stn, geometry).
I attempted to use the "Join by Attributes" tool to merge the geometry with the wind speed data, but the tool doesn't seem to support adding geometry directly to the joined table. I do have Longitude and Latitude columns in my tabular data, but I'd prefer to copy the geometry directly without creating new columns for the coordinates.

The missing geometry attribute :

I'm aware of how to achieve this using Python, but I'm curious if there's a way to do it purely with QGIS tools.
My objective : to copy the geometry column to the table with the wind speed measurements.

Whta if you join vice versa i.e. meteorological data to stations? Otherwise, you can try a Virtual Layer, that supports a geometry column.
